# Knitr html formatting issue

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable, kableextra

The values in the dataframe is warped when knitting to html. It happens when value is less that 3 characters as shown below. -5770 is converted properly to `(5770)` but -577 results in `577.` with an li element appended after. Is this a bug with knitr or an error in my code?

```
round_numeric <- function(num, prec = 0) {
  return (round(as.numeric(num), prec))
}

format_numeric <- function(num, prec = 0) {
  rounded_num <- abs(round_numeric(num, prec))
  res <- format(rounded_num, nsmall = prec, big.mark = ',', trim = TRUE)
  return (ifelse(num >= 0, res, sprintf('(%s)', res)))
}

col1 <- format_numeric(-5770)
col2 <- format_numeric(-577)
col3 <- format_numeric(300)

df <- t(data.frame(row1 = c(col1, col2, col3)))

df %>%
  kable(align = 'c', format = 'html') %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive"))
```

Correct Output in R-studio:

[image]

Wrong output in html file using **knit to html** with R-studio:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is the `(577)` or any whole number inside a bracket get phrased by pandocs into an ordered list.
To prevent this you can disable this in you YAML, just add the following.

```
output: 
  html_document:
    md_extensions: "-fancy_lists"
```

Comment: Hi George, doing the above removes the list but why is there no list for (5770) ?

Comment: It would, but you have formatted `-5770` to read `"(5,770)"` not `"(5770)"`. If you didn't have the comma then it would be phrased into an ordered list